# Webmin error - change permissions on directory by File Manager

Tags: centos, chmod, chown, webmin

When i try to change permissions,owner or create directory by Webmin File manager i receive below errors

```
    Failed to change permissions: 256
Error opening directory /%2Fhome No such file or directory

chown: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/%2Fhome/test': No such file or directory
```

Operating system    CentOS Linux 6.10

Webmin version  1.930

Kernel and CPU  Linux 2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64 on x86_64

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      194G  139G   46G  76% /
tmpfs                 1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M  126M  326M  28% /boot
```

Someone have suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in webmin 1.930, below the official fix.

https://github.com/webmin/webmin/commit/1f5600967f2d7873a443122db2298a06d1d7fd0b